# Unable to locate package lighttpd1.5

Tags: apt, vagrant, lighttpd

I try to install the issue tracking tool youtrack and the installation instruction recommends lighttpd 1.5 with it.

```
sudo apt-get install lighttpd
```

Will only install version 1.4 – for 1.5 I followed this [instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/lighttpd#Getting_1.5_.28L.2B-L.29).

I’ve added the key and made an apt-get update but when I try to call this command:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get install lighttpd1.5 lighttpd1.5-mod-magnet
```

This error message shows up:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package lighttpd1.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lighttpd1.5'
E: Unable to locate package lighttpd1.5-mod-magnet
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lighttpd1.5-mod-magnet'
```

I am using a clean ubuntu trusty64 box for vagrant.
How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `sudo apt-get install lighttpd1.5 lighttpd1.5-mod-magnet` fails is as of the time of writing, that version doesn't exist. The latest version is 1.4.35 and is available [here](http://www.lighttpd.net/download/)

Source: http://www.lighttpd.net/download/